# JavaScript won't output to text field

Tags: javascript, html

My homework is to build an HTML page with JavaScript code to get from a user the current weather condition and output a recommendation based on the weather. I think I've written the code correctly, but my code won't output anything to the text field. Instead, Chrome gives me this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`.  I don't understand this error. Here is the code. Thank you for any help you can give me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Weather Recommendation</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
function weather() {
    //Get the user input
    var condition = document.weather.condition.value;

    //Choose the output
    var output;
    if (condition == "snow") {
        output = "go south";
    }
    else if (condition == "rain") {
        output = "don't forget your umbrella";
    }
    else if (condition == "wind") {
        output = "don't forget your jacket";
    }
    else if (condition == "fog") {
        output = "don't drive";
    }
    else if (condition == "sun") {
        output = "skip school, go hiking";
    }

    //Display the output
    document.weather.recommendation.value = output;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="weather">
    Weather condition <input type="text" name="condition" size="8"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="weather()">Recommendation</button>
    <input type="text" name="recommendation" readonly>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't getting `document.weather.recomendation`

Comment: It might be trying to use the form object in the onClick instead of the function. Try renaming the function to something else.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting"?  How would I get it?

Comment: You can do something like `var recommendation = document.getElementsByName("recommendation")[0]`

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: What @Barmar's asking is interesting. We need to know the line of the exception because `weather()` should works fine and there is no other place(apparently) that can be throwing that exception.

Comment: The error is coming from the line in the body where the <button> tag is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pietu1998 was correct. It was trying to access the form name when you called weather(). I am not sure why but changing the name did the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function yourWeather() {
    //Get the user input
    var condition = document.weather.condition.value;

    //Choose the output
    var output;
    if (condition == "snow") {
        output = "go south";
    }
    else if (condition == "rain") {
        output = "don't forget your umbrella";
    }
    else if (condition == "wind") {
        output = "don't forget your jacket";
    }
    else if (condition == "fog") {
        output = "don't drive";
    }
    else if (condition == "sun") {
        output = "skip school, go hiking";
    }

//Display the output
document.weather.recommendation.value = output;


}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="weather">
    Weather condition <input type="text" name="condition" size="8"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="yourWeather()">Recommendation</button>
    <input type="text" name="recommendation" readonly>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's happening because all form names are automatically added to the `document` and `window` objects, and the latter causes them to become global variables.